# carbon design system v11 with react - customizing tokens

Tags: reactjs, carbon-design-system

I'm trying to use carbon design system V11 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@carbon/react) with React (app started using create-react-app) and I am unable to figure out how to customize separate tokens for global theme overrides.
So far in `App.scss` I'm defining the global theme with

```
@use '@carbon/react/scss/themes';

@use '@carbon/react/scss/theme' with (
  $theme: themes.$g100,
);

@use '@carbon/react';
```

This works, the theme is set to g100.

From here I'd like to change `$interactive-01` or `$button-primary` token so that it applies to the whole theme.
It's completely unclear from documentation how to do that, although documentation here specifies that per token overrides are possible (https://v11.carbondesignsystem.com/guidelines/themes/overview/#customizing-a-theme)
I'm assuming I am having trouble because documentation is not React specific.

If someone ran into this and knows the answer, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See this example [here](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon/blob/main/examples/custom-theme/src/index.scss) / [docs](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon/blob/main/packages/styles/docs/sass.md)

```
@use '@carbon/react/scss/components/button/tokens' as button-tokens with (
  $button-primary: #f00
);
```